# Bring MS Word Application to the front using ComfyJ

Tags: java, ms-word, java-native-interface, com-interop

I'm using ComfyJ 2.7 to try and open a new Word document in MS Word 2007 on Windows 7. I have been create the word document and save it but the application remains minimized in the task bar.

I have tried using the following calls on the application to try and activate the window and bring it to the fore.

```
app.activate();
app.getActiveWindow().activate();
app.getActiveDocument().activate();
```

App.activate seems to make the application request that it move to the fore because the task bar item starts flashing, but it does not bring the word application to the fore.

Has anyone been able to use comfyJ to successfully interop with MS Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is actually caused by new rules of focus in Windows 7.
Applications cannot force themselves other windows into focus, they can only notify that they want focus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the

```
 app.GetActiveDocument().ActiveWindow.WindowState
```

property?

if the taskbar just flashes, it sounds like maybe the document is being started minimized. You may just need to set windowstate to normal.